# Having scoped script functions

Tags: vimscript

I have written two functions two select inner and outer indent levels, which work perfectly.

However I tried to use vim scoping alà `function scope#name`, which sadly doesn't seem to work in my case:

```
onoremap <silent> iz :<c-u>call <sid>sick#iz_motion(0)<cr>
onoremap <silent> az :<c-u>call <sid>sick#iz_motion(&tabstop)<cr>                     
vnoremap <silent> iz :<c-u>call <sid>sick#iz_motion(0)<cr>                            
vnoremap <silent> az :<c-u>call <sid>sick#iz_motion(&tabstop)<cr>    

function s:sick#iz_motion(margin)                                                     
  let l:cur_indent = indent(line("."))                                                
  while indent(line('.') - 1) >= l:cur_indent - a:margin                              
    \ && getline(line('.') - 1) != ''                                                 
    execute 'normal k'                                                                
  endwhile                                                                            

  execute "normal V"  
  while indent(line('.') + 1) >= l:cur_indent - a:margin                              
    \ && getline(line('.') + 1) != ''                                                 
    execute 'normal j'                                                                
  endwhile                                                                            
endfunction
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't mix the `s:` prefix and the autoload syntax. Doing so would make no sense: the `s:` prefix is designed to limit the scope to the current script, while the autoload syntax with `#` is designed for autoloading exported functions (that is, functions that are available outside the current script).

Use either just `s:name` (if you only need it to be available from the current script) or `filename#name` (if you want to call it from other scripts). Since you're using it in a mapping, you need to export it; so you'll have to use the autoload syntax.

See [`:help write-library-script`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/usr_41.txt.html#write%2dlibrary%2dscript) and [`:help local-function`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#local%2dfunction).